# How to make a recyclerView overScroll showing another view behind it?

Tags: android

I want my recyclerView to be draggable down and have a button behind it. For example, this is how the telegram archive is shown.

I don't know where should I start? I am setting an attribute "android:overScrollMode" in the recyclerview.
But what's next? Please guide me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide source code to understand better @Olesya